# LibVLC DXVA2 Windows C++ Hardware Acceleration

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, libvlc, dxva

I want to decode a h264 RTSP stream using DXVA2 Accelerated decoder. In VLC it does work but in my code  have the following output:

```
avcodec generic warning: threaded frame decoding is not compatible with DXVA2, disabled
avcodec generic debug: available hardware decoder output format 61 (dxva2_vld)
avcodec generic debug: available hardware decoder output format 128 (d3d11va_vld)
avcodec generic debug: available software decoder output format 12 (yuvj420p)
core generic debug: looking for hw decoder module matching "any": 1 candidates
core generic debug: no hw decoder modules matched
```

Is this a problem with NV12 conversion? Is there a way to force DXVA2?

Thanks

CODE:

```
    #include <windows.h>
#include <opencv2\core\core.hpp>
#include <opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

#include <windows.h>
#include <ctime>
#include <vlc/vlc.h>

// RTSP address
const char* rtspAddress = "rtsp://admin:admin@192.168.0.245/live_st1";
// Video resolution WxH
cv::Size rtspRes(1920, 1080);

struct VideoDataStruct
{
    int param;
};

int done = 0;
libvlc_media_player_t *mp;
unsigned int videoBufferSize = 0;
uint8_t *videoBuffer = 0;

void cbVideoPrerender(void *p_video_data, uint8_t **pp_pixel_buffer, int size)
{
    if (size > videoBufferSize || !videoBuffer)
    {
        printf("Reallocate raw video buffer %d bytes\n", size);
        free(videoBuffer);
        videoBuffer = (uint8_t *)malloc(size);
        videoBufferSize = size;
    }

    // videoBuffer = (uint8_t *)malloc(size);
    *pp_pixel_buffer = videoBuffer;
}
void cbVideoPostrender(void *p_video_data, uint8_t *p_pixel_buffer, int width, int height, int pixel_pitch, int size, int64_t pts)
{
    // Unlocking
    //CloseHandle(hMutex);

}

//static void handleEvent(const libvlc_event_t* pEvt, void* pUserData)
//{
//    libvlc_time_t time;
//    switch (pEvt->type)
//    {
//    case libvlc_MediaPlayerTimeChanged:
//        time = libvlc_media_player_get_time(mp);
//        printf("MediaPlayerTimeChanged %lld ms\n", (long long)time);
//        break;
//    case libvlc_MediaPlayerEndReached:
//        printf("MediaPlayerEndReached\n");
//        done = 1;
//        break;
//    default:
//        printf("%s\n", libvlc_event_type_name(pEvt->type));
//    }
//}

clock_t startTime[8];
int framesReceivedThisSecond[8];

int main()
{


    // VLC pointers
    libvlc_instance_t *inst;
    libvlc_media_t *m;
    void *pUserData = 0;

    VideoDataStruct dataStruct;

    // VLC options
    char smem_options[1000];

    // RV24
    sprintf(smem_options
            , "#transcode{vcodec=RV24}:smem{"
              "video-prerender-callback=%lld,"
              "video-postrender-callback=%lld,"
              "video-data=%lld,"
              "no-time-sync},"
            , (long long int)(intptr_t)(void*)&cbVideoPrerender
            , (long long int)(intptr_t)(void*)&cbVideoPostrender
            , (long long int)(intptr_t)(void*)&dataStruct
            );

    const char * const vlc_args[] = {
        "-I", "dummy",            // Don't use any interface
        "--ignore-config",        // Don't use VLC's config
        "--extraintf=logger",     // Log anything
        "--verbose=4",            // Be verbose
        //        "--ffmpeg-hw",
        //        "-vvv",
        "--ffmpeg-hw",
        "--avcodec-hw=any",
        "--sout", smem_options    // Stream to memory

    };

    // Launch VLC
    inst = libvlc_new(sizeof(vlc_args) / sizeof(vlc_args[0]), vlc_args);

    // Create a new item
    m = libvlc_media_new_location(inst, rtspAddress);



    // Create a media player playing environement
    mp = libvlc_media_player_new_from_media(m);

    //    libvlc_event_manager_t* eventManager = libvlc_media_player_event_manager(mp);
    //    libvlc_event_attach(eventManager, libvlc_MediaPlayerTimeChanged, handleEvent, pUserData);
    //    libvlc_event_attach(eventManager, libvlc_MediaPlayerEndReached, handleEvent, pUserData);
    //    libvlc_event_attach(eventManager, libvlc_MediaPlayerPositionChanged, handleEvent, pUserData);

    //libvlc_video_set_format(mp, "RV24", 240, 320, 240 * 3 );

    // play the media_player
    libvlc_media_player_play(mp);


    // Create a window for displaying the video
    std::string winName("Demo Video");
    cv::namedWindow(winName, cv::WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

    cv::Mat frame;
    int key = 0;

    // Endless loop, press Esc to quit
    while (key != 27)
    {

        // Check for invalid input
        if (videoBuffer)
        {
            // CV_8UC3 = 8 bits, 3 chanels
            frame = cv::Mat(rtspRes, CV_8UC3, videoBuffer);
        }


        if (frame.rows == 0 || frame.cols == 0)
            continue;

        int stream_number=0;
        framesReceivedThisSecond[stream_number]++;
        long    duration = ( std::clock() - startTime[stream_number] );
        if(duration>1000)
        {
            std::cout<<"\n"<<"FPS "<<stream_number<<" : "<<framesReceivedThisSecond[stream_number]<<"\n";
            startTime[stream_number] = std::clock();
            framesReceivedThisSecond[stream_number]=0;
        }

        cv::imshow(winName, frame);
        key = cv::waitKey(33);
    }


    libvlc_release(inst);

}
```

FULL LOG:

```
core libvlc debug: Copyright © 1996-2016 the VideoLAN team
core libvlc debug: revision 2.2.3-37-g888b7e89
core libvlc debug: configured with ../extras/package/win32/../../../configure  '--enable-update-check' '--enable-lua' '--enable-faad' '--enable-flac' '--enable-theora' '--enable-twolame' '--enable-quicktime' '--enable-avcodec' '--enable-merge-ffmpeg' '--enable-dca' '--enable-mpc' '--enable-libass' '--enable-x264' '--enable-schroedinger' '--enable-realrtsp' '--enable-live555' '--enable-dvdread' '--enable-shout' '--enable-goom' '--enable-caca' '--disable-sdl' '--enable-qt' '--enable-skins2' '--enable-sse' '--enable-mmx' '--enable-libcddb' '--enable-zvbi' '--disable-telx' '--enable-nls' '--host=i686-w64-mingw32' '--build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu' 'build_alias=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu' 'host_alias=i686-w64-mingw32' 'PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/opt/intel/opencl:' 'PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR=/home/svlad/DEV/vlc/contrib/i686-w64-mingw32/lib/pkgconfig'
core libvlc debug: using multimedia timers as clock source
core libvlc debug:  min period: 1 ms, max period: 1000000 ms
core libvlc debug: searching plug-in modules
core libvlc debug: loading plugins cache file C:\DEV\VLCStreamProcessor\build-untitled-Desktop_Qt_5_5_1_MSVC2013_32bit-Debug\debug\plugins\plugins.dat
core libvlc debug: recursively browsing `C:\DEV\VLCStreamProcessor\build-untitled-Desktop_Qt_5_5_1_MSVC2013_32bit-Debug\debug\plugins'
core libvlc debug: saving plugins cache C:\DEV\VLCStreamProcessor\build-untitled-Desktop_Qt_5_5_1_MSVC2013_32bit-Debug\debug\plugins\plugins.dat
core libvlc debug: plug-ins loaded: 418 modules
core libvlc debug: translation test: code is "C"
core libvlc debug: CPU has capabilities MMX MMXEXT SSE SSE2 SSE3 SSSE3 SSE4.1 SSE4.2 FPU 
core playlist debug: creating audio output
core audio output debug: looking for audio output module matching "any": 6 candidates
directsound audio output debug: found 2 devices
core audio output debug: using audio output module "directsound"
core playlist debug: keeping audio output
core interface debug: looking for interface module matching "logger,none": 16 candidates
logger interface: VLC media player - 2.2.4 Weatherwax
logger interface: Copyright © 1996-2016 the VideoLAN team
logger interface: 
Warning: if you cannot access the GUI anymore, open a command-line window, go to the directory where you installed VLC and run "vlc -I qt"
logger interface: using logger.
logger interface warning: no log filename provided, using `vlc-log.txt'
logger interface debug: opening logfile `vlc-log.txt'
core libvlc debug: VLC media player - 2.2.4 Weatherwax
core libvlc debug: Copyright © 1996-2016 the VideoLAN team
core libvlc debug: revision 2.2.3-37-g888b7e89
core libvlc debug: configured with ../extras/package/win32/../../../configure  '--enable-update-check' '--enable-lua' '--enable-faad' '--enable-flac' '--enable-theora' '--enable-twolame' '--enable-quicktime' '--enable-avcodec' '--enable-merge-ffmpeg' '--enable-dca' '--enable-mpc' '--enable-libass' '--enable-x264' '--enable-schroedinger' '--enable-realrtsp' '--enable-live555' '--enable-dvdread' '--enable-shout' '--enable-goom' '--enable-caca' '--disable-sdl' '--enable-qt' '--enable-skins2' '--enable-sse' '--enable-mmx' '--enable-libcddb' '--enable-zvbi' '--disable-telx' '--enable-nls' '--host=i686-w64-mingw32' '--build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu' 'build_alias=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu' 'host_alias=i686-w64-mingw32' 'PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/opt/intel/opencl:' 'PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR=/home/svlad/DEV/vlc/contrib/i686-w64-mingw32/lib/pkgconfig'
core interface debug: using interface module "logger"
core generic debug: creating audio output
core audio output debug: looking for audio output module matching "any": 6 candidates
directsound audio output debug: found 2 devices
core audio output debug: using audio output module "directsound"
core generic debug: keeping audio output
core input debug: Creating an input for 'rtsp://192.168.0.245/live_st1'
core stream output debug: using sout chain=`transcode{vcodec=RV24}:smem{video-prerender-callback=15667245,video-postrender-callback=15667630,video-data=3471900,no-time-sync},'
core stream output debug: stream=`smem'
core stream out debug: looking for sout stream module matching "smem": 22 candidates
core stream out debug: set config option: sout-smem-video-prerender-callback to 15667245
core stream out debug: set config option: sout-smem-video-postrender-callback to 15667630
core stream out debug: set config option: sout-smem-video-data to 3471900
core stream out debug: set config option: sout-smem-time-sync to (null)
core stream out debug: using sout stream module "stream_out_smem"
core stream output debug: stream=`transcode'
core stream out debug: looking for sout stream module matching "transcode": 22 candidates
core stream out debug: set config option: sout-transcode-vcodec to RV24
stream_out_transcode stream out debug: Checking video codec mapping for RV24 got RV24 
stream_out_transcode stream out debug: codec video=RV24 0x0 scaling: 0.000000 0kb/s
core stream out debug: using sout stream module "stream_out_transcode"
core input debug: using timeshift granularity of 50 MiB, in path 'C:\Users\BCDVideo\AppData\Local\Temp'
core input debug: `rtsp://admin:admin@192.168.0.245/live_st1' gives access `rtsp' demux `' path `admin:admin@192.168.0.245/live_st1'
core input debug: specified demux `any'
core input debug: creating demux: access='rtsp' demux='any' location='admin:admin@192.168.0.245/live_st1' file='\\admin:admin@192.168.0.245\live_st1'
core demux debug: looking for access_demux module matching "rtsp": 12 candidates
live555 demux debug: version 2016.01.12
live555 demux debug: RTP subsession 'video/H264'
core input debug: selecting program id=0
live555 demux debug: setup start: 0.000000 stop:0.000000
live555 demux debug: We have a timeout of 60 seconds
live555 demux debug: spawned timeout thread
live555 demux debug: play start: 0.000000 stop:0.000000
core demux debug: using access_demux module "live555"
core decoder debug: looking for packetizer module matching "any": 23 candidates
packetizer_h264 decoder debug: found NAL_SPS (sps_id=0)
packetizer_h264 decoder debug: found NAL_PPS (pps_id=0 sps_id=0)
core decoder debug: using packetizer module "packetizer_h264"
core input debug: starting in sync mode
core demux meta debug: looking for meta reader module matching "any": 2 candidates
lua demux meta debug: Trying Lua scripts in C:\Users\BCDVideo\AppData\Roaming\vlc\lua\meta\reader
lua demux meta debug: Trying Lua scripts in C:\DEV\VLCStreamProcessor\build-untitled-Desktop_Qt_5_5_1_MSVC2013_32bit-Debug\debug\lua\meta\reader
core demux meta debug: no meta reader modules matched
core input debug: `rtsp://admin:admin@192.168.0.245/live_st1' successfully opened
core input debug: switching to async mode
core input debug: Buffering 0%
core input debug: Buffering 3%
core input debug: Buffering 10%
core stream output debug: adding a new sout input (sout_input:00c21c50)
core input debug: Buffering 13%
stream_out_transcode stream out debug: creating video transcoding from fcc=`h264' to fcc=`RV24'
core input debug: Buffering 16%
core generic debug: looking for decoder module matching "any": 43 candidates
core input debug: Buffering 20%
core input debug: Buffering 23%
avcodec generic debug: CPU flags: 0x0107d3db
core input debug: Buffering 30%
avcodec generic debug: trying to use direct rendering
core input debug: Buffering 33%
avcodec generic debug: allowing 4 thread(s) for decoding
core input debug: Buffering 36%
avcodec generic warning: threaded frame decoding is not compatible with DXVA2, disabled
core input debug: Buffering 40%
avcodec generic debug: avcodec codec (H264 - MPEG-4 AVC (part 10)) started
core input debug: Buffering 43%
avcodec generic debug: using slice thread mode with 4 threads
core input debug: Buffering 50%
core generic debug: using decoder module "avcodec"
core input debug: Buffering 53%
core encoder debug: looking for encoder module matching "any": 20 candidates
core input debug: Buffering 56%
core input debug: Buffering 60%
avcodec encoder debug: CPU flags: 0x0107d3db
core input debug: Buffering 63%
avcodec encoder debug: Time base for probing setted to 1/1000000
core input debug: Buffering 70%
avcodec encoder debug: Time base set to 1/1000000
core input debug: Buffering 73%
avcodec encoder debug: found encoder Raw video
core input debug: Buffering 76%
core encoder debug: using encoder module "avcodec"
core input debug: Buffering 80%
core encoder debug: removing module "avcodec"
core input debug: Buffering 83%
core input debug: Buffering 90%
core input debug: Buffering 93%
core input debug: Buffering 96%
core input debug: Stream buffering done (1002 ms in 834 ms)
core input debug: Decoder wait done in 0 ms
avcodec generic debug: available hardware decoder output format 61 (dxva2_vld)
avcodec generic debug: available hardware decoder output format 128 (d3d11va_vld)
avcodec generic debug: available software decoder output format 12 (yuvj420p)
core generic debug: looking for hw decoder module matching "any": 1 candidates
core generic debug: no hw decoder modules matched
avcodec generic warning: plane 0 not aligned
avcodec generic warning: disabling direct rendering
stream_out_transcode stream out debug: decoder aspect is 1.761468:1
stream_out_transcode stream out debug: source pixel aspect is 0.990826:1
stream_out_transcode stream out debug: scaled pixel aspect is 0.990826:1
stream_out_transcode stream out debug: source 1920x1080, destination 1920x1080
stream_out_transcode stream out debug: source fps 30/1, destination 30/1
stream_out_transcode stream out: input interval 33333 (base 1)
stream_out_transcode stream out: output interval 33333 (base 1)
stream_out_transcode stream out debug: encoder aspect is 1920:1090
core filter debug: looking for video filter2 module matching "any": 58 candidates
swscale filter debug: 1920x1080 (1920x1090) chroma: J420 -> 1920x1080 (1920x1090) chroma: RV24 with scaling using Bicubic (good quality)
core filter debug: using video filter2 module "swscale"
core stream out debug: Filter 'Swscale' (0089a2cc) appended to chain
stream_out_transcode stream out debug: destination (after video filters) 1920x1090
core encoder debug: looking for encoder module matching "any": 20 candidates
avcodec encoder debug: CPU flags: 0x0107d3db
avcodec encoder debug: Time base for probing setted to 1/30
avcodec encoder debug: Time base set to 1/30
avcodec encoder debug: found encoder Raw video
core encoder debug: using encoder module "avcodec"
stream_out_transcode stream out warning: Reseting video sync
stream_out_transcode stream out warning: Reseting video sync
stream_out_transcode stream out warning: Reseting video sync
stream_out_transcode stream out warning: Reseting video sync
avcodec encoder warning: almost fed libavcodec with a frame in the past (current: 1518755, last: 1518769)
avcodec encoder warning: almost fed libavcodec with a frame in the past (current: 1518756, last: 1518769)
avcodec encoder warning: almost fed libavcodec with a frame in the past (current: 1518757, last: 1518769)
avcodec encoder warning: almost fed libavcodec with a frame in the past (current: 1518758, last: 1518769)
avcodec encoder warning: almost fed libavcodec with a frame in the past (current: 1518759, last: 1518769)
avcodec encoder warning: almost fed libavcodec with a frame in the past (current: 1518760, last: 1518769)
avcodec encoder warning: almost fed libavcodec with a frame in the past (current: 1518761, last: 1518769)
avcodec encoder warning: almost fed libavcodec with a frame in the past (current: 1518762, last: 1518769)
avcodec encoder warning: almost fed libavcodec with a frame in the past (current: 1518763, last: 1518769)
avcodec encoder warning: almost fed libavcodec with a frame in the past (current: 1518764, last: 1518769)
stream_out_transcode stream out warning: Reseting video sync
stream_out_transcode stream out warning: Reseting video sync
avcodec encoder warning: almost fed libavcodec with a frame in the past (current: 1518784, last: 1518795)
live555 demux debug: tk->rtpSource->hasBeenSynchronizedUsingRTCP()
core input error: ES_OUT_RESET_PCR called
avcodec encoder warning: almost fed libavcodec with a frame in the past (current: 1518785, last: 1518795)
core input debug: Buffering 0%
core input debug: Buffering 3%
core input debug: Buffering 6%
core input debug: Buffering 10%
core input debug: Buffering 13%
core input debug: Buffering 20%
core input debug: Buffering 23%
core input debug: Buffering 26%
core input debug: Buffering 30%
core input debug: Buffering 33%
core input debug: Buffering 40%
core input debug: Buffering 43%
core input debug: Buffering 46%
core input debug: Buffering 50%
core input debug: Buffering 53%
core input debug: Buffering 60%
core input debug: Buffering 63%
core input debug: Buffering 66%
core input debug: Buffering 70%
core input debug: Buffering 73%
core input debug: Buffering 80%
core input debug: Buffering 83%
core input debug: Buffering 86%
core input debug: Buffering 90%
core input debug: Buffering 93%
core input debug: Stream buffering done (1002 ms in 817 ms)
core input debug: Decoder wait done in 0 ms
stream_out_transcode stream out warning: Reseting video sync
stream_out_transcode stream out warning: Reseting video sync
stream_out_transcode stream out warning: Reseting video sync
stream_out_transcode stream out warning: Reseting video sync
avcodec encoder warning: almost fed libavcodec with a frame in the past (current: 1518834, last: 1518837)
avcodec encoder warning: almost fed libavcodec with a frame in the past (current: 1518835, last: 1518837)
avcodec encoder warning: almost fed libavcodec with a frame in the past (current: 1518836, last: 1518837)
avcodec encoder warning: almost fed libavcodec with two frames with the same PTS (1518837)
stream_out_transcode stream out warning: Reseting video sync
stream_out_transcode stream out warning: Reseting video sync
```

Comment: did you get any answer to this ? I am facing this same problem.